# Queryable web api

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api, iqueryable

I've got a Web API where I'd like to offer some (limited) queryable endpoints for stuff like paging, ordering and pre-selecting results (database-wise: columns included in the dto). Things are working great so far, however I have many heavily bloated controller methods with lots of technical stuff and I wondered if there's an easier way to my requirements.

Typical controller looks like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetEntities(int page = MaximumPageIndex, 
    int pageSize = MinimumPageSize,
    string orderBy = null,
    [FromUri] EntitySearchCriteria criteria = null)
{

    // ensure that page/pageSize lies within possible boundaries
    page = page.ToMinimum(MinimumPageIndex);
    pageSize = pageSize.ToBounds(MinimumPageSize, MaximumPageSize);

    // create any criteria for entity if none is available
    criteria = criteria ?? new AnyEntitySearchCriteria();

    // create ordering expressions based on string
    var orderOptions = orderBy != null
        ? ExpressionBuilder.CreateSelector<Entity, dynamic>(orderBy)
        : ExpressionBuilder.CreateSelector<Entity, dynamic>("Id");

    // create paging options
    var pagingOptions = new PagingOptions<Entity, dynamic>(page, pageSize, orderOptions);

    try {

        // get total count from database
        var totalCount = _repository.Count();

        // get entities by criteria specification (IMemberSpecification<T, TMember>)
        var results = _repository.GetEntitiesByCriteria(criteria,
            x = new BlablaDto {}  // apply result selectors (not shown in example,
            // map to paged list
            pagingOptions).ToPagedList(page, pageSize, totalCount);

        // create "paged" response with paging http headers (rfc 5988)
        return Request.CreatePagedResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, results);
        ...
}
```

This, of course, over and over again, for many entities which often look the same. Now I know there's Microsoft OData, but I can't and won't use it for numerous reasons (only works on IQueryable, strange responses - for instance: paging data is included in the json result, not in the HTTP headers).. so, how can I keep my controllers simple and reduce code repetition for this very task?

Comment: The answer lies unto how _repository is designed and implemented... I can't see it from the code.

Comment: @Werlang Basic CRUD plus a method 'GetEntities()' that takes an ISpecification, an IQueryOptions (for sorting/paging which gets applied on the underlying IQueryable returned by the query provider) and a selector expression to return a subset of fields and/or DTO mapping.

Comment: this Repository.GetEntities() can be moved to a template method in a base controller... then have your Controller.GetEntities() implement all this logic and handle over to this specific fetch, for each entity type.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller has a lot of logic and you should consider moving that logic to another layer such as an API Facade/Engine layer. In order to clean up the input though you can setup your search filters with some inheritance built in. I've had to do that in many recent projects.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public interface IPaginatedFilter {

    int DefaultLimit { get; }
    int MaximumLimit { get; }
    List<string> SupportedOrderBy { get; }
    bool IsAscendingByDefault { get; }
}

[DataContract]
public sealed class PaginationInput 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "limit", Order = 2)]
    public int Limit { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "offset", Order = 3)]
    public int Offset { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "orderBy", Order = 4)]
    public string OrderBy { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "orderByDirection", Order = 5)]
    public string OrderByDirection { get; set; }

}

/// <summary>
///     Base search filter
/// </summary>
public class SearchBase {
    /// <summary>
    ///     Results page information
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "page", Order = 1)]
    public PaginationInput Page { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Search phrase applicable to any member of the inheriting search filter
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "any", Order = 1)]
    public string Any { get; set; }

}

public class EntitySearchCriteria : SearchBase, IPaginatedFilter {

    // columns to provide search functions for


    #region Implementation of IPaginatedFilter

    public int DefaultLimit {
        get { return 20; }
    }

    public int MaximumLimit {
        get { return 50; }
    }

    public List<string> SupportedOrderBy {
        get { return new List<string>
        {
            // columns that support ordering
        }; }
    }

    public bool IsAscendingByDefault {
        get { return true; }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

This way you will have the same API for all your search filters. Your controller really should look like

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetEntities(
        [FromUri] EntitySearchCriteria filter = null)
{

    // process input using your service layer

    // generate response

}
```

If you need to validate filter input first, then send the input to a validation layer before attempting to process the request. **Separation of concerns specially at the boundary of your application will pay off tremendously in the long run**.

Comment: If like me, you didn't know how use parameter such as limit or offset during call in url, the formatting is the following http://myurl/api/Entities?page[limit]=30&page[offset]=10